# How to make a python file visible to python notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, jupyter

I have a `.py` file I want to `import` into my notebook. The file is in the same directory as my `.ipynb` file. How to make it visible to that notebook (say files are named `./library.py` and `./experiment.ipynb`)?

Comment: You should be able to `import library` it if they are in the same directory, is that not working?  whats the output of `sys.path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 3 , you should be able to just do `import .library` or `from . import library`. More generally, you need the file to be on your `$PYTHONPATH` (it's unrelated to Jupyter/IPython it's a Python thing), and you should consider [packaging your file](http://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it will probably take you 5 minutes to make it installable and redistributable.